# RxJS5: scan operator converting to array for ngFor

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I am creating a stream that will achieve this:

- get http data
- get socket event and update initial http data every time socket event received
- convert data to array for Angular's `ngFor`

This is what I have:

```
this.subscription = this.http.get('httpService')
.switchMap(httpResult => this.socket.get('socketEvent')
        .scan((data, deltas) => {
            _.each(deltas, function (item) {
                switch (item.type) {
                    case 'a':
                        data.a_list[item.id].value = item.val;
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                        data.b_cells[item.id].value = item.val;
                        break;
                }
            });
            return data;
        }, httpResult)
        .startWith(httpResult)
)
//manipulates same object as scan operator?  
.map(data => Object.keys(data.a_list).map(k => data[k]))
.subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
});
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor='let item of data'>{{ item }}</div>
```

All works fine the first time around, but on the second socket event inside the `scan` operator, the data has been converted to an array. It appears that the .`map` operator is manipulating the same object that the `scan` operator is. Is this right?

I was always under the impression that `scan` returned a new object and not the reference, which I assume is what's happening here.

If that is the case how can I convert a nested object inside the output of my stream into an array and still use `scan`?